# Bilinear, symmetric function $f(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)$ defines an inner product

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, inner-products

I'm learning Euclidean geometry, specifically inner products and Euclidean spaces, and need help with the following exercise:

In the vector space $\mathbb R^2$, we write $\mathbf x = (x_1, x_2), \mathbf y = (y_1, y_2)$ ect.  for points $\mathbf x, \mathbf y$ in terms of a given base. For simplicity we assume that we are working over the field $\mathbb R$.

> Which of the following bilinear, symmetric functions $f(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)$ define an inner product?
>
> $(1) \quad f = 2x_1y_1 - 3x_1y_2 - 3x_2y_1 + 3x_2y_2$
>
> $(2) \quad f = 3x_1y_1 - 2x_1y_2 - 2x_2y_1 + 4x_2y_2$
>
> Give the norm which is defined by the inner product (when it's defined). Describe the curves $f(\mathbf  x, \mathbf x) =$ constant in each case.

First of all, I don't understand what it means for $f$ to be symmetric. Does this mean that I can interchange the $x_i$ and $y_i$ in each of the linear term of $f$?

I did go back several times to the definition of an inner product but it is still unclear to me how I should solve this problem. I wanted to show that the $3$ axioms defined by an inner product are satisfied (or not), i.e. the symmetry $<\mathbf x, \mathbf y> = <\mathbf y, \mathbf x>$ (since we are working over the field $\mathbb R$ and not $\mathbb C$), the linearity in the first component and the positive definiteness.

For the symmetry, maybe because the function $f(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)$ is symmetric I can write

$$f(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) = <\mathbf x, \mathbf y>  = 2x_1y_1 - 3x_1y_2 - 3x_2y_1 + 3x_2y_2 = 2y_1x_1 - 3y_2x_1 - 3y_1x_2 + 3y_2x_2 = <\mathbf y, \mathbf x>$$

but I'm not sure if this is any good.
I would also appreciate any help on the $2$ sub-questions.

Answer (score 0):

The bilinear form $\;f\;$ is symmetric if $\;f(\vec x,\vec y)=f(\vec y,\vec x)\;$ .

In the given example, you have to check symmetry as defined above. For example with the first one:

$$f((x_1,x_2),\,(y_1,y_2))=2x_1y_1-3x_1y_2-3x_2y_1+3x_2y_2\stackrel?=$$

$$\stackrel?=2y_1x_1-3y_1x_2-3y_2x_1+3y_2x_2=f((y_1,y_2),\,(x_1,x_2))$$

Check carefully the above: does that equality there with the ? sign is true? Then the form is symmetric. Otherwise, it is not.

Now you try this again also with the second given form

Answer (score 0):

The question in the box already says that they're bilinear and symmetric. All that you have to check is whether they're positive-definite.

For the first function, $f(x,x) = 2x_1^2 - 3x_1x_2 - 3x_2x_1 + 3x_2^2$ . If the value of $f$ is constant, then this is a quadratic equation in 2 variables, which represents a [conic section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form). The coefficients are $A = 2,\,B = -6,\,C = 3$; and $B^2-4AC = {^+ 12}$, so this is a hyperbola. Also, if $x = (1,1)$, then $f(x,x) = 2 - 3 - 3 + 3 = {^- 1}$, so $f$ is not positive-definite.

For the second function, $f(x,x) = 3x_1^2 - 2x_1x_2 - 2x_2x_1 + 4x_2^2$ . The coefficients are $A = 3,\,B = -4,\,C = 4$; and $B^2-4AC = {^- 32}$, so this is an ellipse. Also, the expression can be rewritten as a sum of squares: $f(x,x) = 3x_1^2 - 4x_1x_2 + 4x_2^2 = (\sqrt 2\,x_1)^2 + (x_1 - 2x_2)^2$ . Any sum of squares is positive, unless all of the terms are zero; so $f$ is positive-definite.

---

You are correct about symmetry.

The first function is symmetric only because the two mixed terms' coefficients are the same (-3). Ditto the second function, (-2).